# How to edit the HTML code of just one page of my wordpress website?

Tags: html, css, json, wordpress, woocommerce

So for some pages of my Wordpress website I created a big block of code conisiting many images and links, which I need to change from time to time. Because this was built with a plugin like Elementor manually changing hundreds of images/links would take forever.

If I could edit the source code of just this page I would copy the source code, run it through my script which would change all the links/images in seconds and paste it back in the webpage source code.

If this wasn't clear enough hear is my thought process in steps:

1: Having a webpage with content which can only (afaik) be edited through a plugin like Elementor

2: Instead copying the part with the content from the source code

3: Chaging this source code within seconds through a script

4: Pasting the new source code back into the webpage sp it is updated with the new content

Comment: I know I could just create the content directly through HTML but I have barely any knowledge of that and the block builder made it exactly how I want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it depends on how elementor is storing the images in the image block, chances are that is will be contained in shortcodes e.g. `[vietpic]<img src="wp-content/nam.jpg [/vietpic]`   you *should* be able to see this by going to the page with these images and then selecting 'Text' on the content editor. The editor will switch from the visual blockbuilding to the code which you can then copy out, run your script on and place elsewhere. Just make sure that you get the whole block, like any containing elements for instance. If this doesn't work out I'd suggest navigating to the page on the frontend, inspecting the element via the browsers inspector then selecting the container, click 'edit as html' then copy out the code. You can then run your script on this source code then paste it into an elementor custom html block.